# Can it be a harm to Google SEO if I will insert <br> inside <h1>?

Tags: seo, html, google-search, heading

Can it be harm for my site in manner of SEO if I will insert BR tag inside H1 tag?

```
<h1> keyword1 <br/> 
     keyword2  <br/> 
     keyword2  <br/> 
</h1>
```

Comment: Not sure why you would do this, but no. Google does not care one whit. Just remember that Google does have a render engine that could be confused by this... but it should not effect search performance.

Comment: You're thinking too much. But "keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3" - really?

Comment: @w3d has a point. Header tags should be conversational. Do not chase keywords so directly- in fact, the old keyword chase is a bit of a misnomer. Create content for humans and not machines.

Comment: @closetnoc That's not always the case, and I think proper use of  header tags is much less about being conversational and much more about organizing your content. You should often think of your title tags as a table of contents. For a screen reader, it is a table of contents. Although that doesn't mean that conversational headers aren't beneficial, and you're definitely right to say to create contents for humans and not machines.

Comment: @Alesana Google is not a keyword centric search engine anymore despite what the SEOs say. It is a semantics centric search engine. I recommend conversational tags for two reasons, humans, and a better semantic understanding of what your content is about. In a few places I described semantics and how sentence structure effects SEO. This is why simple sentences with active voice work best. Two things I tend to fail at. [grin] Taking a machine view on tags is also helpful. Someday, when I have more time, I will write something more clear on this topic. Cheers!!

Answer (score 6):

It can be appropriate to use [`br`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) in heading elements. An [example](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/common-idioms.html#sub-head) from the HTML5 spec:

```html
<h1>Ramones <br>
<span>Hey! Ho! Let's Go</span> 
</h1>
```

If it’s appropriate in your case depends on your actual content (a heading listing three keywords is most likely not a good idea in the first place).

However, even for inappropriate uses of `br`, there is no reason to assume that it would affect your ranking in Google Search.

Comment: if you're using that markup, ditch the br element and add display:block to the span

Comment: @albert: This would only work for users with CSS support. For other users, it would not be clear where the musician name ends and where the title starts.

Comment: who doesn't have css support? i'm aware of the no js user community, but no css? is that a thing?

Comment: @albert: Probably depends on how many users are needed to become "a thing" ;) The popular browsers are not the only clients consuming HTML. There are text browsers, feed readers, search engines, users that use CSS user stylesheets (overwriting all of your CSS), screen readers (some might not make a reading pause in this example without `br` or a textual delimiter), etc. In this HTML5 example, the `br` was added exactly for this purpose: to convey the semantics (here is a break), not just the styling (show a new line).

Answer (score 0):

Theres a chance you'll be in the bad books with Google. It all depends on what the resulting screen looks like to various users when you're done.

For example, if you create a super simple page where each character in the title (H1 tag) are at least an inch high in height and you use a couple of breaks (BR tags) inside it, then most of the content of the page will be below-the-fold. It's a bad experience if a user has to scroll on a page in order to see the content.

Also, I'd avoid the BR in H1 because it may throw some SEO tools off when you check your web page within them, thereby producing inaccurate or unwanted results.

If you need to make lists, you can use `<ol>` and `<ul>` and format the spacing and font styles using CSS. and put the list within your document. The H1 tag isn't meant for listing items, especially the way you are doing it.

Comment: Hey,it's not what I am trying to do ...it was just an example the purpose was to div my top headline for two parts I have images on the right side and my h1 on the left side so i just need it to be fit to screens but not break the line any where according to the screen size I wanted it to looks good on any screen size

Answer (score -1):

inside an  tag is an error syntax :P

Comment: [h1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) has a content mode of [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) which includes br. So no, it isn't an error.